# ztree loaded table: How to match variables

Tags: ztree

I am trying to match data in an experiment, created through individual input, to a payoff structure that is stored in a txt I have (successfully) loaded into zTree before.
However, I do not know, how to find the - in specific - payoff to the corresponding input in the txt file that is defined there.

The txt file looks as follows:
[NK table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3I5g.png)

Within the game, the "Input" variable is generated by users and now the payoff needs to be found corresponding to the input generated. Can anyone help out here?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TABLENAME.find(condition, variable)` function retrieves the first value that fits a condition.

Assuming the user has the variable `MyInput` in the `subjects` table, this program running on `subjects` would do the trick:

`NKtable.find(Input == :MyInput, Payoff)`

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your reply and your help. The command makes total sense, however I still receive an error message. The line "MyInput = format(D11,0)+format(D12,0)+format(D13,0)+format(D14,0)+format(D15,0)+format(D16,0)+format(D17,0)+format(D18,0)+format(D19,0)+format(D110,0);" comes before and is in a subject table, collecting the subject's input and formatting it into a string variable
When entering your line into a second subjects table, an error message pops up...

Comment: interesting. what does the error say? can you check also if the table `NKtable` is loaded correctly? (and a screenshot of that probably helps)

Comment: When entering PayoffR1 = NKtable.find(Input == MyInput, Payoff); two error messages appear: 1. "Comparing incompatible types" and 2. "Error: in program. Item: "program"" https://www.dropbox.com/s/tzkyumg8lj98nom/Anmerkung%202020-02-08%20152107.png?dl=0

Comment: "Comparing incompatible types" suggest that MyInput is not really string. Given you already the function `format` there, I guess the `+` doesn't really work out on string concentration. I unfortunately cannot test that now.

Two things I can suggest: Try to concentrate strings by using `stringinsert()` function. Or just keep everything in number format. About the second, I guess you can use `power()` function to make things easier. You can check the comment I added here: https://stackloverflow.com/questions/60129253/how-to-combine-several-input-data-from-items-to-one-string-variable-in-ztree